# upgrade 01 january 2020

Tags: updates

before the update
I had the theme of Sierra Light Os
and it worked very well but very well
actually everything worked fine
but after the update I have some problems
with minimize buttons
and the appearance of the application center doesn't look good too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check out does the default elementary os theme works well? If it is ok, you have to wait for an update of the SieraLightOs theme or choose another one.